# Tracking nodejs memory usage: how to open a .heaptimeline file?

Tags: node.js

I'm tracking the memory usage of a NodeJS application.

To do that I changed the `npm run start` command alias adding a `-- inspect` flag.

When I run the app now it I can open a tab in chrome called "chrome://inspect/" and I can see the NodeJS process running.
After clicking on "inspect" I can trace the memory usage and I can save the heap in a file with a ".heaptimeline" extension.

The problem is that I don't know with what application I can open that file again to see the heap profile. What program should I use? I can't open if with Chrome and I find very little information online

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome can read that file. Open DevTools in Chrome, open tab "Memory", click button "Load" and select your .heaptimeline file. If you already have some dump there, delete it first, otherwise button "Load" will not appear